# How to avoid HTML Table breaks the page in the mobile devices?

Tags: html-table

I am working with the HTML table, it works perfectly on the computer. But when I am loading it on the mobile the page getting break I mean the width of the page is increasing for adjusting the table columns. You can see the issue on this https://teluguhitflopmovieslist.blogspot.com/2019/06/Sneha-Movies-List-Hits-Flops-Blockbusters-Average-Box-Office-Verdict.html run this in mobile. I want table shouldn't increase the width of the page. For example, you see the Wikipedia tables in mobile https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneha_(actress)#Filmography in this table not breaking the page this is what I am looking for. Sorry, I tried my best to convey the issue, if you have a solution please help.

```
<table border="2" class="wikitable sortable">

<tbody>
<tr align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<th>Year
</th>
<th>Film
</th>
<th>Role
</th>
<th>Language
</th>
<th>Notes
</th></tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2">2000</td>
<td><i>Ingane Oru Nilapakshi</i></td>
<td>Manasi</td>
<td><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Malayalam" title="Malayalam">Malayalam</a></td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Ennavale" title="Ennavale">Ennavale</a></i></td>
<td>Lakshmi</td>
<td><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Tamil_language" title="Tamil language">Tamil</a></td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="6">2001</td>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Tholi_Valapu" title="Tholi Valapu">Tholi Valapu</a></i></td>
<td>Soumya</td>
<td><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Telugu_language" title="Telugu language">Telugu</a></td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Aanandham" title="Aanandham">Aanandham</a></i></td>
<td>Viji</td>
<td rowspan="2">Tamil</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Kannathil_Muthamittal" title="Kannathil Muthamittal">Kannathil Muthamittal</a></i></td>
<td>Indira</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Priyamaina_Neeku" title="Priyamaina Neeku">Priyamaina Neeku</a></i>/<i><a class="mw-redirect" href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Kadhal_Sugamanathu" title="Kadhal Sugamanathu">Kadhal Sugamanathu</a></i></td>
<td>Sandhya</td>
<td>Telugu <br />
Tamil</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Paarthale_Paravasam" title="Paarthale Paravasam">Paarthale Paravasam</a></i></td>
<td>Chella</td>
<td>Tamil</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Hanuman_Junction_(film)" title="Hanuman Junction (film)">Hanuman Junction</a></i></td>
<td>Meenkashi</td>
<td>Telugu</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="7">2002</td>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Pammal_K._Sambandam" title="Pammal K. Sambandam">Pammal K. Sambandam</a></i></td>
<td>Malathi Anand</td>
<td rowspan="14">Tamil</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Punnagai_Desam" title="Punnagai Desam">Punnagai Desam</a></i></td>
<td>Priya</td>
<td><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Tamil_Nadu_State_Film_Award_for_Best_Actress" title="Tamil Nadu State Film Award for Best Actress">Tamil Nadu State Film Award for Best Actress</a>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Unnai_Ninaithu" title="Unnai Ninaithu">Unnai Ninaithu</a></i></td>
<td>Radha</td>
<td><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Filmfare_Award_for_Best_Supporting_Actress_%E2%80%93_Tamil" title="Filmfare Award for Best Supporting Actress – Tamil">Filmfare Award for Best Supporting Actress – Tamil</a>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Yai!_Nee_Romba_Azhaga_Irukke!" title="Yai! Nee Romba Azhaga Irukke!">Yai! Nee Romba Azhaga Irukke!</a></i></td>
<td>Raji</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/King_(2002_film)" title="King (2002 film)">King</a></i></td>
<td>Tamil</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a class="mw-redirect" href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/April_Madhathil" title="April Madhathil">April Madhathil</a></i></td>
<td>Swetha</td>
<td>Nominated, <a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Filmfare_Award_for_Best_Actress_%E2%80%93_Tamil" title="Filmfare Award for Best Actress – Tamil">Filmfare Award for Best Actress – Tamil</a>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Virumbugiren" title="Virumbugiren">Virumbugiren</a></i></td>
<td>Thavamani</td>
<td><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Tamil_Nadu_State_Film_Award_for_Best_Actress" title="Tamil Nadu State Film Award for Best Actress">Tamil Nadu State Film Award for Best Actress</a><br />
Nominated&nbsp;– Filmfare Award for Best Actress&nbsp;– Tamil
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2">2003</td>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Vaseegara_(film)" title="Vaseegara (film)">Vaseegara</a></i></td>
<td>Priya Vishwanathan</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Parthiban_Kanavu_(2003_film)" title="Parthiban Kanavu (2003 film)">Parthiban Kanavu</a></i></td>
<td>Sathya,Janani</td>
<td>Nominated&nbsp;– Filmfare Award for Best Actress&nbsp;– Tamil
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="6">2004</td>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Vasool_Raja_MBBS" title="Vasool Raja MBBS">Vasool Raja MBBS</a></i></td>
<td>Janaki Vishwanathan</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Jana_(film)" title="Jana (film)">Jana</a></i></td>
<td>Manimegalai</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Bose_(film)" title="Bose (film)">Bose</a></i></td>
<td>Charu</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Autograph_(2004_film)" title="Autograph (2004 film)">Autograph</a></i></td>
<td>Divya</td>
<td>Nominated&nbsp;– Filmfare Award for Best Actress&nbsp;– Tamil
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Adhu" title="Adhu">Adhu</a></i></td>
<td>Meera</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Venky" title="Venky">Venky</a></i></td>
<td>Sravani</td>
<td>Telugu</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="6">2005</td>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Aayudham_(2005_film)" title="Aayudham (2005 film)">Aayudham</a></i></td>
<td>Maha</td>
<td>Tamil</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a class="mw-redirect" href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Sankranthi_(film)" title="Sankranthi (film)">Sankranthi</a></i></td>
<td>Anjali</td>
<td rowspan="2">Telugu</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Radha_Gopalam" title="Radha Gopalam">Radha Gopalam</a></i></td>
<td>Radha</td>
<td><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Nandi_Special_Jury_Award" title="Nandi Special Jury Award">Nandi Special Jury Award</a>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Chinna_(2005_film)" title="Chinna (2005 film)">Chinna</a></i></td>
<td>Gayathri Vikram</td>
<td rowspan="2">Tamil</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/ABCD_(film)" title="ABCD (film)">ABCD</a></i></td>
<td>Chandra</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a class="mw-redirect" href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/That_is_Pandu" title="That is Pandu">That is Pandu</a></i></td>
<td>Anjali</td>
<td rowspan="3">Telugu</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="6">2006</td>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Sri_Ramadasu" title="Sri Ramadasu">Sri Ramadasu</a></i></td>
<td>Kamala</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Evandoi_Srivaru" title="Evandoi Srivaru">Evandoi Srivaru</a></i></td>
<td>Divya</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Thuruppugulan_(2006_film)" title="Thuruppugulan (2006 film)">Thuruppu Gulan</a></i></td>
<td>Lakshmi</td>
<td>Malayalam</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Pudhupettai" title="Pudhupettai">Pudhupettai</a></i></td>
<td>Krishnaveni</td>
<td>Tamil</td>
<td>Nominated&nbsp;– Filmfare Award for Best Actress&nbsp;– Tamil
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a class="mw-redirect" href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Ravi_Shastri_(film)" title="Ravi Shastri (film)">Ravi Shastri</a></i></td>
<td>Bhanu</td>
<td><a class="mw-redirect" href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Kannada_language" title="Kannada language">Kannada</a></td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Manasu_Palike_Mouna_Raagam" title="Manasu Palike Mouna Raagam">Manasu Palike Mouna Raagam</a></i></td>
<td>Gowri</td>
<td rowspan="3">Telugu</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="4">2007</td>
<td><i><a class="mw-redirect" href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Maharadhi" title="Maharadhi">Maharadhi</a></i></td>
<td>Bhairavi</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Madhumasam" title="Madhumasam">Madhumasam</a></i></td>
<td>Hamsa Vahini</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Naan_Avanillai_(2007_film)" title="Naan Avanillai (2007 film)">Naan Avanillai</a></i></td>
<td>Anjali</td>
<td rowspan="4">Tamil</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Pallikoodam_(film)" title="Pallikoodam (film)">Pallikoodam</a></i></td>
<td>Kokila Vetrivel</td>
<td>Nominated&nbsp;– Filmfare Award for Best Actress&nbsp;– Tamil
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="8">2008</td>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Pirivom_Santhippom" title="Pirivom Santhippom">Pirivom Santhippom</a></i></td>
<td>Visalakshi Nadesan</td>
<td><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Tamil_Nadu_State_Film_Award_for_Best_Actress" title="Tamil Nadu State Film Award for Best Actress">Tamil Nadu State Film Award for Best Actress</a> <br />
<a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Vijay_Award_for_Best_Actress" title="Vijay Award for Best Actress">Vijay Award for Best Actress</a><br />
Nominated—<a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Vijay_Award_for_Favourite_Heroine" title="Vijay Award for Favourite Heroine">Vijay Award for Favourite Heroine</a><br />
Nominated&nbsp;– Filmfare Award for Best Actress&nbsp;– Tamil
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Inba_(film)" title="Inba (film)">Inba</a></i></td>
<td>Priya</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Nee_Sukhame_Ne_Korukunna" title="Nee Sukhame Ne Korukunna">Nee Sukhame Ne Korukunna</a></i></td>
<td>Swapna</td>
<td>Telugu</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Pandi_(film)" title="Pandi (film)">Pandi</a></i></td>
<td>Bhuvana</td>
<td>Tamil</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a class="mw-redirect" href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Panduranga_(film)" title="Panduranga (film)">Pandurangadu</a></i></td>
<td>Lakshmi</td>
<td>Telugu</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Kuselan" title="Kuselan">Kuselan</a>/<a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Kathanayakudu_(2008_film)" title="Kathanayakudu (2008 film)">Kathanayakudu</a></i></td>
<td>Herself</td>
<td>Tamil<br />
Telugu</td>
<td>Cameo appearance in the song 'Cinema Cinema'
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Adivishnu" title="Adivishnu">Adivishnu</a></i></td>
<td>Anjali</td>
<td>Telugu</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Silambattam_(film)" title="Silambattam (film)">Silambattam</a></i></td>
<td>Gayathri</td>
<td>Tamil</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2">2009</td>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Achchamundu!_Achchamundu!" title="Achchamundu! Achchamundu!">Achchamundu! Achchamundu!</a></i></td>
<td>Malini Kumar</td>
<td>Tamil</td>
<td><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Edison_Awards_(India)" title="Edison Awards (India)">Edison Award for Best Actress</a><br />
Nominated&nbsp;– Filmfare Award for Best Actress&nbsp;– Tamil
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Amaravathi_(2009_film)" title="Amaravathi (2009 film)">Amaravathi</a></i></td>
<td>Latha Venkat</td>
<td>Telugu</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="6">2010</td>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Goa_(2010_film)" title="Goa (2010 film)">Goa</a></i></td>
<td>Suhasini Fernando</td>
<td rowspan="3">Tamil</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Theeradha_Vilaiyattu_Pillai" title="Theeradha Vilaiyattu Pillai">Theeradha Vilaiyattu Pillai</a></i></td>
<td>Dr. Ramya</td>
<td>Cameo appearance
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a class="mw-redirect" href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Angaadi_Theru" title="Angaadi Theru">Angaadi Theru</a></i></td>
<td>Herself</td>
<td>Cameo appearance
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a class="mw-redirect" href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Pramaani" title="Pramaani">Pramaani</a></i></td>
<td>Janaki</td>
<td rowspan="2">Malayalam</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a class="mw-redirect" href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Shikkar,_The_Hunt" title="Shikkar, The Hunt">Shikkar, The Hunt</a></i></td>
<td>Kaveri</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Vandae_Maatharam" title="Vandae Maatharam">Vandae Maatharam</a></i></td>
<td>Nandhini</td>
<td>Malayalam<br />
Tamil</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="3">2011</td>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Bhavani_IPS" title="Bhavani IPS">Bhavani IPS</a></i></td>
<td>Bhavani</td>
<td rowspan="2">Tamil</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Ponnar_Shankar_(film)" title="Ponnar Shankar (film)">Ponnar Shankar</a></i></td>
<td>Arukkaani</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Rajanna" title="Rajanna">Rajanna</a></i></td>
<td>Lachamma</td>
<td>Telugu</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2">2012</td>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Oru_Kal_Oru_Kannadi" title="Oru Kal Oru Kannadi">Oru Kal Oru Kannadi</a></i></td>
<td>Jennifer</td>
<td rowspan="5">Tamil</td>
<td>Guest appearance
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Murattu_Kaalai_(2012_film)" title="Murattu Kaalai (2012 film)">Murattu Kaalai</a></i></td>
<td>Bhuvana</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>2013</td>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Haridas_(2013_film)" title="Haridas (2013 film)">Haridas</a></i></td>
<td>Amudhavalli</td>
<td>Nominated&nbsp;– Filmfare Award for Best Actress&nbsp;– Tamil  <br />
Nominated—Vijay Award for Best Actress
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="4">2014</td>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Pannaiyarum_Padminiyum" title="Pannaiyarum Padminiyum">Pannaiyarum Padminiyum</a></i></td>
<td>Shanmugam's daughter</td>
<td>Special appearance
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Un_Samayal_Arayil" title="Un Samayal Arayil">Un Samayal Arayil</a></i></td>
<td rowspan="3">Gowri</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a class="mw-redirect" href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Ulavacharu_Biryani" title="Ulavacharu Biryani">Ulavacharu Biryani</a></i></td>
<td>Telugu</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Un_Samayal_Arayil" title="Un Samayal Arayil">Oggarane</a></i></td>
<td>Kannada</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="3">2015</td>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/S/O_Satyamurthy" title="S/O Satyamurthy">S/O Satyamurthy</a></i></td>
<td>Lakshmi</td>
<td>Telugu</td>
<td>Nominated -<a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/5th_South_Indian_International_Movie_Awards" title="5th South Indian International Movie Awards">SIIMA Award for Best Supporting Actress</a>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/JK_Enum_Nanbanin_Vaazhkai" title="JK Enum Nanbanin Vaazhkai">JK Enum Nanbanin Vaazhkai/Rajadhi Raja</a></i></td>
<td>Herself</td>
<td>Tamil<br />
Telugu</td>
<td>Cameo appearance
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Kaaval" title="Kaaval">Kaaval</a></i></td>
<td>Herself</td>
<td>Tamil</td>
<td>Cameo appearance
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>2016</td>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Ore_Mukham" title="Ore Mukham">Ore Mukham</a></i></td>
<td>Bhama</td>
<td rowspan="2">Malayalam</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2">2017</td>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/The_Great_Father" title="The Great Father">The Great Father</a></i></td>
<td>Michelle David</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Velaikkaran_(2017_film)" title="Velaikkaran (2017 film)">Velaikkaran</a></i></td>
<td>Kasthuri</td>
<td>Tamil</td>
<td>Nominated - <a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/7th_South_Indian_International_Movie_Awards" title="7th South Indian International Movie Awards">SIIMA Award for Best Supporting Actress</a>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="4">2019</td>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Vinaya_Vidheya_Rama" title="Vinaya Vidheya Rama">Vinaya Vidheya Rama</a></i></td>
<td>Konidela Gayatri Devi</td>
<td>Telugu</td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a class="mw-redirect" href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Muniratna_Kurukshetra" title="Muniratna Kurukshetra">Muniratna Kurukshetra</a></i></td>
<td><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Draupadi" title="Draupadi">Draupadi</a></td>
<td>Kannada</td>
<td>Post-production
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Untitled film with Dhanush</td>
<td>TBA</td>
<td rowspan="2">Tamil</td>
<td rowspan="2">Filming
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Vaan_(film)" title="Vaan (film)">Vaan</a></i></td>
<td>TBA
</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
<h2>
<span class="mw-headline" id="Television">Television</span><span class="mw-editsection"><span class="mw-editsection-bracket">[</span><a href="https://www.blogger.com/w/index.php?title=Sneha_(actress)&amp;action=edit&amp;section=10" title="Edit section: Television">edit</a><span class="mw-editsection-bracket">]</span></span></h2>
<table class="wikitable sortable">

<tbody>
<tr align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<th>Year
</th>
<th>Program
</th>
<th>Role
</th>
<th>Channel
</th>
<th>Language
</th>
<th>Notes
</th></tr>
<tr>
<td>2013–2014</td>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Melam_Kottu_Thali_Kattu" title="Melam Kottu Thali Kattu">Melam Kottu Thali Kattu</a></i></td>
<td rowspan="2">Host</td>
<td rowspan="2"><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Puthuyugam_TV" title="Puthuyugam TV">Puthuyugam TV</a></td>
<td rowspan="7"><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Tamil_language" title="Tamil language">Tamil</a></td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>2014</td>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Melam_Kottu_Thali_Kattu" title="Melam Kottu Thali Kattu">Melam Kottu Thali Kattu season 2</a></i></td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>2016–2017</td>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Dance_Jodi_Dance" title="Dance Jodi Dance">Dance Jodi Dance</a></i></td>
<td rowspan="5">Judge</td>
<td rowspan="5"><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Zee_Tamil" title="Zee Tamil">Zee Tamil</a></td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2">2017</td>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Dancing_Khilladies" title="Dancing Khilladies">Dancing Khilladies</a></i></td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Zee_Dance_League" title="Zee Dance League">Zee Dance League</a></i></td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>2017–2018</td>
<td><i><a href="https://www.blogger.com/wiki/Dance_Jodi_Dance_(season_2)" title="Dance Jodi Dance (season 2)">Dance Jodi Dance 2.0</a></i></td>
<td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>2019-Present</td>
<td><i>Dance Jodi Dance Juniors</i></td>
<td></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making `<table>`s responsive is a bit tricky, but there are several patterns available that you can utilize. CSS-Tricks has a great article which explores the most common ones and explains pros & cons of each strategy.

https://css-tricks.com/accessible-simple-responsive-tables/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, set media query for mobile devices as you have to decrease the `font-size` for the text on smaller devices.

```
@include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
    .wikitable{
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}
```

or

```
@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
    .wikitable {
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}
```